# Google cloud functions - setInterval function quits after 15 mins

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My app uses a Firebase function that is triggered when my Firebase realtime database is modified.
The function initiates a setInterval function that is supposed to loop for an hour then terminate....HOWEVER it seems to quit after 15mins.
Im guessing this is a restriction put in place by Firebase...does anyone know how I can get around this?
See code below

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//this gets triggered when db is updated
exports.onActiveUpdate = functions.database
  .ref('/pathToRealtimeDb').onUpdate(() => {
    let counter = setInterval(() => {
      //count down from 60 mins to zero then exit 
    }, 60000); //end setInterval
  });
```

Comment: In version 1 of Cloud Functions, an invocation cannot run longer than 9 minutes. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout

Comment: Cloud Functions are initially designed to execute rather short operations. In version 2, the maximum timeout duration is 60 minutes but you should probably refactor your business logic if you want to wait during 15 minutes in a CF doing nothing. For example delegate some work to be executed by a new CF in 15 minutes. What is your exact use case?

Comment: Checkout [Cloud Tasks integration with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions). You can create 2 CFs - the one running above and another that runs after a given interval. Cloud Tasks will trigger that 2nd function based on the time you specify. So you only pay for the time both of your functions run and not the whole 15 minutes just waiting for the time to pass by.